# Why decorations and data is not updating in my VScode extension?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, node-inspector

I am trying to write quokka.js like vscode extension. I am using decorations api to display vars const let values in editor and chrome dev tools inspector node api to run and compile code. In activate function I am subscribing to vscode save document event and getting the values from global scope. But it is working only once. Than data don't updates. Why?

```js
// Import the module and reference it with the alias vscode in your code below
import * as vscode from 'vscode';
import * as inspector from 'inspector';
import * as path from 'path';
import * as util from 'util';
import { memoryUsage, versions } from 'process';
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as kill from 'tree-kill';

// console.log(vscode.Disposable);

const activeTextEditor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;

let decorationTypes: any = [];

const makeDecorationWithText = (
    contentText: string,
    line: number,
    column: number,
    activeEditor: vscode.TextEditor
) => {
    const decorationType = vscode.window.createTextEditorDecorationType({
        after: {
            contentText,
            margin: '20px'
        }
    });

    decorationTypes.push(decorationType);

    const range = new vscode.Range(
        new vscode.Position(line, column),
        new vscode.Position(line, column)
    );

    activeEditor.setDecorations(decorationType, [{ range }]);
};

const clearDecorations = () => {
    if (decorationTypes.length > 0) {
        for (let i = 0; i < decorationTypes.length; i++) {
            activeTextEditor?.setDecorations(decorationTypes[i], []);
            decorationTypes[i].dispose();
        }
        decorationTypes = [];
    } else {
        vscode.window.showInformationMessage('Array is empty');
    }
};

export async function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    clearDecorations();

    let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('coderunner3.coderun', async () => {


        vscode.window.showInformationMessage('Coderun is working!');

        vscode.workspace.onDidSaveTextDocument(async () => {
            const session = new inspector.Session();
            session.connect();

            const post = <any>util.promisify(session.post).bind(session);
            clearDecorations();
            // await post('Memory.forciblyPurgeJavaScriptMemory');
            await post('Runtime.disable');
            // await post('Runtime.addBinding', 'variables');
            await post('Runtime.enable');
            await post('Debugger.enable');
            const activeEditor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
            if (!activeEditor) {
                return;
            }
            const document = activeEditor.document;
            const filename = path.basename(document.uri.toString());
            const { scriptId } = await post('Runtime.compileScript',
                {
                    expression: vscode.window.activeTextEditor?.document.getText(),
                    sourceURL: filename,
                    persistScript: true
                });
            // console.log(scriptId);
            await post('Runtime.runScript', { scriptId });
            const data = await post('Runtime.globalLexicalScopeNames', {
                executionContextId: 1
            });

            // console.log(data.names[0]);

            data.names.map(async (expression: string) => {
                console.log(expression);
                const executionResult = await post('Runtime.evaluate', { expression, contextId: 1 });
                const { value } = executionResult.result;
                // console.log(executionResult.result);
                const { result } = await post('Debugger.searchInContent', {
                    scriptId, query: expression
                });
                // for(let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                //  let test = await post('Runtime.evaluate', { expression: result[i].lineContent, contextId: 1 });
                //  console.log(test);
                // }
                // console.log(executionResult);
                makeDecorationWithText(`${value}`, result[0].lineNumber, result[0].lineContent.length, activeEditor);
            });
            await post('Runtime.disable');
            await post('Debugger.disable');
            // await post('Debugger.setBreakpoint', { scriptId, lineNumber: 1 });
            // await post('CacheStorage.deleteCache', { cacheId: scriptId });
            session.disconnect();
        });
    });

    context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
}

export function deactivate() {
    clearDecorations();
}
```

[image: 1]